# angular modal ui bootstrap: Can i use another controller child of ModalInstanceCtrl?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm new in angular and my english is not very good, so i try to explain my problem the best i can.

I'm using the [ui.bootstrap.modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#modal) in my project, and i need that the modal window i open can be controlled by another controller and not only ModalInstanceCtrl. 
I want to ModalInstanceCtrl manage the common actions in a modal window, (set title, close, etc..) and then another controller (SpecificController) manage specific actions.

So this is my modal template view now:

```
<h1>
   {{title}} 
   <a ng-click="closemodal()">x</a>
</h1>
<div ng-include  src="specificTemplate.html" ng-controller="SpecificController"></div>
```

My idea is that specificTemplate.html and SpecificController can be set as a variables in the future and so having a system for manage modal windows with common actions, and other specific actions for each modal window. The include template works fine, but with the ng-controller label i get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance
```

I have SpeficController defined in my controllers section.

In other similar questions in StackOverflow, the problem were that ng-controller="ModalInstanceCtrl" was set in the template, but i want/need another controller for specific actions as a child one. 
How can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can manage this, but first of all - don't inject `$modalInstance` into `SpecificController`. If you need to close (or dismiss) a modal from within a scope created by the `SpecificController` you can do so by using the `$close()` and `$dismiss()` method available on the scope.

Having said the above your example is a bit too abstract to provide exact guidance so if you could provide a representative use-case using http://plnkr.co/ you would get more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was i was injected $modalInstance in SpecificController, (inherit from a Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V) X(

now i don 't now if is posiible pass the SpecificController name as a var, (the template name work) but this is a different question

Comment: @pkozlowski-opensource http://plnkr.co/edit/OuBIcvbe08FqPc6wjyBq?p=preview I was trying to do it this way, but I'm getting same error in my app, when in the example provided error is missing in `console` window.